# mysql_num_rows() Error being thrown in my Query

Tags: php, mysql

My query keeps giving a

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

error at these 2 rows:

```
$num_pgs = mysql_num_rows($camp_pgs);
            $num_cid = mysql_num_rows($camp_id);
```

In this statement:

```
$userID=PageDB::getInstance()->get_user_id_by_name($_SESSION['user']);
            $result_pg=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages where campaign=" . $campaignID); 
            $result_cid=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM campaign where id=" . $campaignID); 
            $camp_pgs = mysql_query($result_pg);
            $camp_id = mysql_query($result_cid);
            $num_pgs = mysql_num_rows($camp_pgs);
            $num_cid = mysql_num_rows($camp_id);
            $i=0;
                        if ($num_pgs > 0){
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($camp_pgs)):
                 $style = "";
                    if($i%2==0)
```

What I am trying to acchieve here is match 2 columns from 2 seperate tables where if table.column 1 = table.column 2 then list the results in a dynamic table.
The tables queried are "pages" and "campaigns" where I am trying to match column "campaignid" with column "id" respectively.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$camp_id = mysql_query($result_cid);` but before that you have `$result_cid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM campaign where id=" . $campaignID);`. Can you see your mistake?

Comment: Just curiosity, but... why do you write a comment with the solution instead of writing a solution?

Comment: Because this question isn't going to help anyone else who encounters it, it's a localized scenario where one used a resource for mysql_query and I'm not hunting reputation.

Comment: @N.B I agree. It's also a silly mistake that is easily spotted. Why would you query a query? ...

Comment: Yeah, I saw where I went wrong in the statement you pointed out. and corrected it. However, it still returns the mysql_num_rows() error, and it sees that for whatever reason, whenever I try to use the mysql_num_rows() statement I get an error.

Comment: Your code is so messy that you can't spot trivial errors. Make an array and group your queries, query results and number of rows for the results. That way you can immediately see whether you made a mistake. Check for query errors, because queries can fail, yet you still try to run `mysql_num_rows` without checking if you're passing the correct argument. Help yourself before rushing to get help, these are all easily solvable problems.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
 $num_pgs = mysql_num_rows($camp_pgs);
 $num_cid = mysql_num_rows($camp_id);
```

with

```
$num_pgs = mysql_num_rows( $result_pg);
$num_cid = mysql_num_rows($result_cid);
```

REMOVE:

```
 $camp_pgs = mysql_query($result_pg);
 $camp_id = mysql_query($result_cid);
```

Comment: Thanks Ameoo, but I am still getting the error even after fixing my stupid mistakes I made in the queries to begin with. I think I'll try another aproach instead. Thanks all the same :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages, campaign WHERE campaign='".$campaignID."' AND campaign=id;";


// guess you have column "id" in both tables - then use this line
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages AS p, campaign AS c WHERE c.campaign='".$campaignID."' AND c.campaign=p.id;";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code,

```
$userID=PageDB::getInstance()->get_user_id_by_name($_SESSION['user']);
        $result_pg=("SELECT * FROM pages where campaign=" . $campaignID); 
        $result_cid=("SELECT * FROM campaign where id=" . $campaignID); 
        $camp_pgs = mysql_query($result_pg);
        $camp_id = mysql_query($result_cid);
        $num_pgs = mysql_num_rows($camp_pgs);
        $num_cid = mysql_num_rows($camp_id);
        $i=0;
                    if ($num_pgs > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($camp_pgs)):
             $style = "";
                if($i%2==0)
```